# While statement trouble Java

Tags: java

While I was working on a program that simulates a dice, I encountered a problem.
This is the code I wrote (I know it is not good programing at all but I'm learning). It works and of course I know that there is unnesecary parts in it, but is not the problem.

```
 double x ;
 String z ;
 x = Math.random() ;
 z = Double.toString(x) ;
 z = z.substring(2, 3) ;

 while (x>6 || x<1) {

     x =Math.random() ;
     z = Double.toString(x);
     z = z.substring(2, 3) ;
     x = Integer.parseInt(z ); 
 }

 z = Double.toString(x );
 z = z.substring(0, 1) ; 

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Antal prickar: "+z);
```

The problem is that saw that I erlier had an if statement in the while loop and it worked a couple of weeks ago and now when I rewrote the code it is not working.

```
double x ;
String z ;
x = Math.random() ;
z = Double.toString(x) ;
z = z.substring(2, 3) ;

while (x>6 || x<1) {

    if (x>6) {
        x =Math.random() ;
        z = Double.toString(x);
        z = z.substring(2, 3) ;
        x = Integer.parseInt(z ); 
    }
}

z = Double.toString(x );
z = z.substring(0, 1) ; 

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Antal prickar: "+z);
```

Can anyone explain why it is not working because I should be able to put the if statement inside the while loop without it giving me errors right?

Comment: Why are you simulating the roll of a dice like that ?
this line does about all that: int dice1=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);

Comment: You say, "now when i rewrote the code it is not working". What does that mean? What errors or unexpected behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: What errors do you get? What is going wrong?

Comment: How can you guarantee  z = z.substring(2, 3) ; z length is >4

Comment: Formatting your code might be a start, e.g. in order to see where the matching closing braces are. - I did it for you, please check for correctness.

Comment: Simply calling `Math.ceil(Math.random()*6)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your previous code was working (and skipping comments on style etc.) the main problem seems to be the added if-statement.

Consider the case where x = 0:

`while( x > 6 || x < 1)` will run since the condition is satisfied (x is smaller than 1).

`if(x > 6)` is not satisfied though (x is not greater than 6) and thus `x` will never be updated, resulting in an endless loop.

Btw, I'd not use `Math.random()` but rather create a new instance of `Random` and then call `nextInt(6) + 1` to get a random integer between 1 and 6 (both inclusive):

```
Random rand = new Random(); //you might want to store this elsewhere and reuse the instance
int dice = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; //done, random integer between 1 and 6
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `java.lang.Math.random()` to generate a number between and 1 and 6. As that `random()` call returns a value normalized in the 0.0 to 1.0 interval, you choose the first decimal as your candidate value and in the case it is off limits, you repeat the `random()` call to get a new candidate number.

In the second snippet you sent post (the one you say *is not working*), the formatting shows that the `while` loop only contains the `if` statement, and this statement will only do something if `x > 6`, but `x` will never be over 6 as the value is between 0 and 1.

You might be missing this line in the first block before the while loop:

```
x = Integer.parseInt(z );
```

And the `if` condition within the loop shall be removed.

**Edit:** to produce a random value between 1 and 6 the simpliest piece of code I can thing about is:

```
new java.util.Random().nextInt(6) + 1
```